# Implementation of Chainlink Feed Aggregator

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, chainlink

I'm trying to implement chainlink feed aggregator just like it is for ETH and other price feed provided by chainlink.

I have found this FluxAggregator in version 0.6 but currently chainlink has version 0.8 and there is no FluxAggregator in 0.8.
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.6/FluxAggregator.sol

Also I found this FeedRegistry Repo https://github.com/smartcontractkit/feed-registry
This repo has FeedRegistry.sol contract which is implementing 'AggregatorV2V3Interface.sol' from version 0.7 of chainlink.

So its all mixed up and I'm not sure what is the right path to look for implementation of Aggregator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of aggregation used is called "OCR" or "Off-Chain Reporting". FluxAggregator was the previous aggregation method. The code and contracts for OCR can be found in this repo:

https://github.com/smartcontractkit/libocr

Running your own feeds isn't officially supported *yet* (this is being worked on), so there isn't any documentation, but it is possible to run your own feed using that code if you really need to. You could also aggregate a couple of "[Chainlink AnyAPI](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/)" requests in your contract to simulate a feed.

If this is for a hackathon (or just to demo your app) and there's no existing data feed for the data you need, I'd suggest using the "AnyAPI" feature and a single Chainlink node, so you can focus on your application and not on building an oracle network. Once it's time to go to production/mainnet, the Chainlink Labs team can assist you in making a decentralized oracle network. You can reach them here on the [Chainlink website](https://chain.link/data-feeds).

Reference: [OCR Announcement Blog](https://blog.chain.link/off-chain-reporting-live-on-mainnet/)

Comment: Thank you.
Actually, I'm trying to setup multiple nodes (for different type of data, not for crypto prices) with their respective oracles and then setup aggregator which will aggregate results just like chianlink is doing for prices.

So first of all, is it the right strategy to create feed like setup for other type of information?
And secondly, Am I going in right direction or should be using something else provided by chainlink

Comment: The official Chainlink feeds I linked to above are a bit more complicated than the design you are listing, but you can certainly do that (that's what I was talking about in the 2nd paragraph of my answer). If this is or a hackathon (or just to demo your app) and there's no existing data feed for the data you need, I'd suggest using the "AnyAPI" feature and a single Chainlink node. Once it's time to go to mainnet, the Chainlink Labs team can assist you in making a decentralized oracle network. You can reach them here:
https://chain.link/data-feeds

Comment: Thanks. Yes for now its for hackathon but will need proper setup for mainnet